# PHP Date diff with a difference

Tags: php, date, datediff

Please bear with me as I try to explain my predicament. I need to somehow get the difference between two dates by reversing a function I have to add months and years?

**Problem**
The date add function provided with PHP >= 5.3 does not add dates in the manner I require.
**Example: +3 Months to 30Nov = 2Mar**

**Solution**
I use the function below (code ref 2) to produce the results I need.
**Example: +3 Months to 30Nov = 28Feb**

However when using the below (code ref 1) to calculate the difference it does so based on the addition function provide with PHP >= 5.3 in that I get 2 instead of 3 months difference between 30Nov and 28Feb.

If anyone could help come up with an accurate date diff based on the code ref 2 logic I, and I'm sure others in the same boat would be very grateful.

<< CODE REF 1 >>

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2000-11-30');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2001-02-28');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%m'); // 2

$datetime1 = new DateTime('2000-11-30');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2001-03-02');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%m'); // 3
?>
```

<< CODE REF 2 >>

```
<?php       
$datetime = new DateTime('2000-11-30');
$y = 0;
$m = 3;
$d = 0;
if ($d>0){
    $datetime->add(new DateInterval('P'.$d.'D'));
}
if ($d<0){
    $datetime->sub(new DateInterval('P'.$d.'D'));
}
if ($y!=0){
    $init=clone $datetime;
       $modifier=$y.' years';
       $datetime->modify($modifier);
       while ($datetime->format('m')!=$init->format('m')){
        $datetime->modify('-1 day');
    }
}
if ($m!=0){
    $init=clone $datetime;
    $modifier=$m.' months';
    $back_modifier =-$m.' months';
    $datetime->modify($modifier);
    $back_to_init= clone $datetime;
    $back_to_init->modify($back_modifier);
    while ($init->format('m')!=$back_to_init->format('m')){
        $datetime->modify('-1 day');
        $back_to_init= clone $datetime;
        $back_to_init->modify($back_modifier);   
    }
}
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d'); // 2001-02-28
?>
```

**SOLUTION FOUND**

By changing the way we use the original function we instead find out the number of years and months as desired, many thanks to all the helpful suggestions. The reason for y=1 and m=4 is because the year starts at one and the month starts at one, otherwise it would be 0 and 3 as originally requested if starting at zero.

```
<?php
function date_yr_mth($date1='2000-11-30',$date2='2001-02-28'){
    $y1 = date("Y", strtotime($date1));
    $m1 = date("n", strtotime($date1));
    $d1 = date("j", strtotime($date1));
    $y2 = date("Y", strtotime($date2));
    $m2 = date("n", strtotime($date2));
    $d2 = date("j", strtotime($date2));
    $t2 = date("t", strtotime($date2));
    $cm_diff = $m2-$m1;
    $cy_diff = $y2-$y1;
    if ($d2>=$d1){
        $add_mth1 = 1;
    }else{
        $add_mth1 = 0;
    }
    $add_mth2 = 12*$cy_diff+$cm_diff;
    if ($d2==$t2 && $d2<$d1){
        $add_mth3 = 1;
    }else{
        $add_mth3 = 0;
    }
    $total_mths = $add_mth1+$add_mth2+$add_mth3;
    $arr = array();
    $arr['y'] = floor(($total_mths-1)/12)+1;
    $arr['m'] = $total_mths-($arr['y']-1)*12;
    print_r($arr);
    // [y] => 1
    // [m] => 4
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you explain what it is exactly that you're trying to achieve with your addMonths() function in code ref 2?

Comment: I have tweaked code ref 2 to show the example of adding 3 months to 30Nov and for the result to be 2001-02-28.

Comment: So you ask us to derive the reasoning behind the whole thing from your code? Why not explain in simple words, with a few examples, how you'd like your algorithm to work?

Comment: code ref 2 is not my own code it is a tweaked version of one posted on php.net, the code works great however I need a matching logic one for a date diff which I have been unable to create.

Comment: If you have a solution the SO way is to post it as an answer and accept that rather than embedding it in your question where it is unlikely to be seen. Having said that, your solution is not particularly good and is verging on being a hack.

Answer (score 2):

The way to approach this is to extend DateTime and overide the add() and sub() methods to behave as you want them to. That, after all is one of the advantages of OOP.

The way to get your desired behaviours is to set the day of the month to the 1st before doing calling add() or sub() and then restoring the original or highest possible day afterwards.

My first attempt is below, not thoroughly tested, but adding 1 month to 31st Jan gave 28th Feb, which, I believe is your desired behaviour:-

```
class MyDateTime extends \DateTime
{
    public function add($interval)
    {
        $oldDay = (int)$this->format('d');
        $this->setDate((int)$this->format('Y'), (int)$this->format('m'), 1);
        parent::add($interval);
        $maxDay = (int)$this->format('t');
        if($oldDay > $maxDay){
            $this->setDate((int)$this->format('Y'), (int)$this->format('m'), $maxDay);
        } else {
            $this->setDate((int)$this->format('Y'), (int)$this->format('m'), $oldDay);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function sub($interval)
    {
        $oldDay = (int)$this->format('d');
        $this->setDate((int)$this->format('Y'), (int)$this->format('m'), 1);
        parent::sub($interval);
        $maxDay = (int)$this->format('t');
        if($oldDay > $maxDay){
            $this->setDate((int)$this->format('Y'), (int)$this->format('m'), $maxDay);
        } else {
            $this->setDate((int)$this->format('Y'), (int)$this->format('m'), $oldDay);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function diff($dateTime2, $absolute = false)
    {
        if((int)$this->format('t') > (int)$dateTime2->format('t')){
            $this->setDate((int)$this->format('Y'), (int)$this->format('m'), (int)$dateTime2->format('t'));
        }
        if((int)$this->format('t') < (int)$dateTime2->format('t')){
            $dateTime2->setDate((int)$dateTime2->format('Y'), (int)$dateTime2->format('m'), (int)$this->format('t'));
        }
        return parent::diff($dateTime2, $absolute);
    }
}
```

[Here is a working example using your exampe dates](http://3v4l.org/SSNN8)

[Here is an example using the diff() method](http://3v4l.org/9Lioe) as you can see it gives a 3 month difference. You can also see that adding the resulting DateInterval to the original date results in the second date.

The sub() method may require a bit more thought, but I don't have time just now. I'll take a more thorough look if I get a few spare minutes later.

Comment: thanks vascowhite - I will use this new method, however what I really need is to use a datediff function which produces a result the same as the inputs used for your MyDateTime class. It's really confusing me and I'm now beginning to think that it's not even possible.

Comment: See my edit for overriding `DateTime::diff()`. I think it should work, but can't test it thoroughly just now.

Answer (score 1):

This way you would get the absolute difference between months without taking in account the day.

```
 <?php
function getMonthDiff($firstMonth, $secondMonth)
{
    $firstMonth  = $firstMonth->format("Y") * 12 + $firstMonth->format("m");
    $secondMonth = $secondMonth->format("Y") * 12 + $secondMonth->format("m");

    return abs($firstMonth - $secondMonth);
}


$datetime1 = new DateTime('2000-11-30');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2001-02-28');
echo getMonthDiff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo "<br />";
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2000-11-30');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2001-03-02');
echo getMonthDiff($datetime1, $datetime2);
```

Comment: I may have to use this method as it technically produces the correct results based on the two dates in question. However it may be incorrect on other dates. I'm just trying to figure out if what I'm trying to achieve is even possible (without the function knowing how a date has been modified in the first place).

Comment: If I understood your question correctly then it should produce correct result on any dates used.