# Is there any php in built function which return total months difference?

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to get the total months difference between to dates. if the interval is greater than 1 year then the function should calculate the month for the year also. i have tried -

```
//create dates
        $fromDate = date(
            'Y-m-d', 
            strtotime(
                '01-'.str_replace("/", "-", $companyData['from'])
            )
        );
        $toDate   = date(
            'Y-m-d', 
            strtotime(
                '01-'.str_replace("/", "-", $companyData['to'])
            )
        );
        $from     = date_create($fromDate);
        $to       = date_create($toDate);
        $interval = date_diff($from, $to);//debug($interval);
        //calculate and return in number of months format
        return $interval->format('%m');
```

`date format - '01-07-2014'` in the variables.

but it does not consider the years. only the differrence between months field is returned. i can explode it and do it manually.so plz if any inbuilt function is there the suggest.guys i hav the working code -

```
//calculate and return in number of months format
$diff = ($interval->m + ($interval->y * 12));
```

i just want some built in function if any so that it reduces the time as i am calculating it in side a loop and also a lot of data processing is there.

thanx in advance.

Comment: A build-in function that is _that_ specific? No, not that I'm aware of, but adding `$interval->format('Y')/12` isn't that much trouble, is it? it'll give you the years interval in months...

Comment: please give an example what your ``$companyData['from']`` data looks like

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem .. that can be done. but if there is any built in function and that is quick then it will be more help ful as am calculating it inside an loop.

Comment: @Sgt: Like I said: no, I don't think there is. What I'm suggesting is to call `format` twice, and perform some simple calculations on those values... that's hardly going to impact performance...

Comment: for this ($interval->m + ($interval->y * 12)) is calculating. @EliasVanOotegem

Comment: @sgt: Yes, it's early in the morning for me, so `/12` should've been `*12`, but you got the gist of it... stick with that, there's no function/method readily available to you, so compute the months yourself. It's not difficult

Comment: yup.. i have done it and updated the question also. just wanted to reduce the time.

Comment: @sgt please notice my answer check first if the year is greater then 1 year because your logic won'T work for dates that are closer then 1 year.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Date diff with a difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203983/php-date-diff-with-a-difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `DateTime` functions to get your results

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('01-07-2014');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('01-07-2016');
$dateDiff = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

$difftotalMonths = $dateDiff->y >= 1 ? ($dateDiff->y * 12) + $dateDiff->m : $dateDiff->m;

var_dump($difftotalMonths);
//int(24)
```

Comment: i have done this.. but i just wanted a solution that should automatically calculate it.

Comment: what on this answer is not "automatically" ? just pass your variables in ``DateTime($companyData['from']);``

Comment: u r doing it in oop style and same is done in the answer in procedural style. not much difference.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding 2 new variables like $fromyear and $toyear and then calculate the difference between those.
then calculate the difference between months and make a calculation like this: (diffyear * 12) + diffmonth